# How to create dates array out of two dates?

Tags: clickhouse

I got two columns `start` and `finish` how can I create an array which will contain all the dates between this two dates?

For example, `start=2020/09/01`   `finish=2020/09/03` and as result I want to have `[2020/09/01, 2020/09/02, 2020/09/03]`

I thought about `timeSlots()` function, but it seems to work only with time format, maybe there is another function like `dateSlots()` within Clickhouse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 2 other ways:

```sql
SELECT 
    toDate('2020-09-01') AS start,
    toDate('2020-09-03') AS end,
    arrayMap(x -> toDate(x), timeSlots(toDateTime(start), toUInt32((end - start)*24*60*60), 24*60*60)) AS timeslot_result,
    arrayMap(x -> toDate(x), range(toUInt32(start), toUInt32(end) + 1)) AS range_result

/*
┌──────start─┬────────end─┬─timeslot_result──────────────────────────┬─range_result─────────────────────────────┐
│ 2020-09-01 │ 2020-09-03 │ ['2020-09-01','2020-09-02','2020-09-03'] │ ['2020-09-01','2020-09-02','2020-09-03'] │
└────────────┴────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────┘
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate numbers from days diff and then generate new dates based on it

```sql
SELECT groupArray(
   toDate('2020-09-01') + INTERVAL number DAY
)
FROM numbers(
    toUInt64(
        dateDiff(
            'day',
            toDate('2020-09-01'),
            toDate('2020-09-03')
        ) + 1
    )
)
```